# Add hours column to regular list of minutes, group by it, and average the data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have looked for similar questions, but none seems to be addressing the following challenge. I have a pandas dataframe with a list of minutes and corresponding values, like the following:

```
minute value
0        454
1        434
2        254
```

The list is a year-long list, thus counting 60 minutes * 24 hours * 365 days = 525600 observations.

I would like to add a new column called hour, which indeed expresses the hour of the day (assuming minutes 0-59 are 12AM, 60-119 are 1AM, and so forth until the following day, where the sequence restarts).

Then, once the hour column is added, I would like to group observations by it and calculate the average value for every hour of the year, and end up with a dataframe with 24 observations, each expressing the average value of the original data at each hour n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integer and remainder division you can get the hour.

```
df['hour'] = df['minute']//60%24
```

If you want other date information it can be useful to use January 1st of some year (not a leap year) as the origin and convert to a `datetime`. Then you can grab a lot of the date attributes, in this case hour.

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['minute'], unit='m', origin='2017-01-01').dt.hour
```

Then for your averages you get the resulting 24 row Series with:

```
df.groupby('hour')['value'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'minute': np.arange(525600), 'value': np.arange(525600)})

# set time format
df['minute'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['minute'], unit='m')

# calculate mean
df_new = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='minute', freq='1H'))['value'].mean().reset_index()
```

Although, you don't need `hour` column explicity to calculate these value, but if you want to get it, you can do it by:

```
df_new['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['minute']).dt.hour
```